# include svg within mustache file

Tags: mustache

I hve the following mustache file, from the patternlab template and I'd like to include an svg file that is another folder, my mustache file looks like this so far, and I just want to include it just after the body tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="{{ htmlClass }}">
    <head>
        <title>{{ title }}</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css?{{ cacheBuster }}" media="all" />
        <link href="../../fonts/fonts.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" rel="stylesheet"  />
        <!-- Begin Pattern Lab (Required for Pattern Lab to run properly) -->
        {% pattern-lab-head %}
        <!-- End Pattern Lab -->

    </head>
    <body class="{{ bodyClass }}">
```

I know in PHP you can do this    but how in mustache? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the code for the svg implementation in a seperate mustache file. Than you can easily include the mustache file with {{> folder/svg-file-name }}